# Setting Default Value for Lightning Web Component Test

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components

I'm writing unit test for my LWC.  For some of the methods and features that I'm testing, it looks at the values of a field and then does something.  For example:

```js
let field = this.template.querySelector('.field-class');
if (field.value == 'Matching Value') {
    let secondField = this.template.querySelector('.another-field-class');
    secondField.value = 'Default Value';
}
```

So when I'm writing the test I'll have something like this:

```js
describe('test-element', () => {
    var element;

    beforeEach(() => {
        element = createElement('c-test-element', {
            is: TestElement
        });

        document.body.appendChild(element);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it('should set the default value'), () => {
        let field = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('.field-class');
        field.value = 'Matching Value';

        const form = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form');
        form.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('load'));

        let secondField = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('.another-field-class');
        expect(secondField.value).toBe('Default Value');
    });
});
```

It works fine, but the problem is that when I run the test I get a warning message like this:

> console.warn
>   node_modules/@lwc/engine/dist/commonjs/es2017/engine.js:208
>         [LWC warning]: If property value decorated with @api in [object:vm undefined (213)] is used in the template, the value
>   Matching Value set manually may be overridden by the template,
>   consider binding the property only in the template.

I've found a way to avoid this by adding getters and setters to the the actual component and using those, but that doesn't seem like the best solution since I only need them for tests.  Especially since to get full code coverage I have to write specific test for them.

Is there a way to set the value of a field for a test without getting the warning message?

I apologize for any typos in the code, I freehand wrote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for raising this issue. We recently cleaned up our warning and error messages because some of them were un-actionable or just creating too much noise. This particular warning will no longer be logged in a future release:
https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/commit/1afe614236cd0a2c801617afbbdeaeea9b8a30ff

Comment: Awesome, that's good news.

Comment: @aaron, I am still getting these warnings. How do I avoid them? By adding getters and setters?

Comment: @Anee, I'm still getting them as well.  I guess it never got fixed.  It's annoying, but I just ignore them.